# parsing records with key value pairs in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file with millions of records like this

2017-07-24 18:34:23|CN:SSL|RESPONSETIME:23|BYTESIZE:1456|CLIENTIP:127.0.0.9|PROTOCOL:SSL-V1.2

Each record contains around 30 key-value pairs with "|" delimeter. Key-value pair position is not constant.
Trying to parse these records using python dictionary or list concepts.
Note: 1st column is not in key-value format

Comment: try `csv` module...

Answer (score 0):

your file is basically a `|`-separated `csv` file holding first the timestamp, then 2 fields separated by `:`.

So you could use `csv` module to read the cells, then pass the result of `str.split` to a `dict` in a gencomp to build the dictionary for all elements but the first one.

Then update the dict with the timestamp:

```
import csv

list_of_dicts = []
with open("input.txt") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter="|")
    for row in cr:
        d = dict(v.split(":") for v in row[1:])
        d["date"] = row[0]
        list_of_dicts.append(d)
```

`list_of_dicts` contains dictionaries like

```
{'date': '2017-07-24 18:34:23', 'PROTOCOL': 'SSL-V1.2', 'RESPONSETIME': '23', 'CN': 'SSL', 'CLIENTIP': '127.0.0.9', 'BYTESIZE': '1456'}
```

Comment: I have few keys containing ":" in data as well. Like BACKEND:10.207.161.106:443....so split is failing giving below reason ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #30 has length 4; 2 is required

Answer (score 0):

You repeat the below process for all the lines in your code. I am not clear about the date time value. So I haven't included that in the input. You can include it based on your understanding.

```
import re
given = "CN:SSL|RESPONSETIME:23|BYTESIZE:1456|CLIENTIP:127.0.0.9|PROTOCOL:SSL-
V1.2"
results = dict()
list_for_this_line = re.split('\|',given)
for i in range(len(list_for_this_line)):
    separated_k_v = re.split(':',list_for_this_line[i])
    results[separated_k_v[0]] = separated_k_v[1]
print results
```

Hope this helps!